# Why this query does not work ? It is a type of subquery right ? and it also seems logically correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select ROUND(LONG_W,4)
from STATION
WHERE LAT_N = MAX(SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < 137.2345);
```

Why this query will not work for the question .

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-15/problem

Comment: `this query will not work` ... the syntax is valid.  _How_ does your query not work?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SELECT MAX(LAT_N) FROM STATION` ?

Comment: Should be `SELECT ROUND(LONG_W,4) from STATION WHERE LAT_N = (SELECT MAX(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < 137.2345);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this easy way.

```
select ROUND(LONG_W,4) from STATION WHERE LAT_N < 137.2345 ORDER BY LAT_N DESC LIMIT 0,1
```